# Hiding a simple batch window

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, cmd

I've searched this and some pages came which weren't really useful or were too complicated (I am not a skilled batch file programmer!)! What I need is to run a batch file in hidden form (no console window). The batch file will not be called from external application or code. It will be clicked on by the client and then I want no console pages to be shown (only pages which are called by call command should be shown)! The batch file is exactly as follows:

```
@echo off
call setup.exe
IF EXIST "C:/caillog" goto tracking 
IF NOT EXIST "C:/caillog" goto end


:tracking
call dotnet4.exe
call ClientService.msi
goto end

:end
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I use VBScripts to open it hidden, like this:

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run("%batchfile%"), 0, True
```

for e.g the bat file I want to run is `run.bat` then I'll do like this

```
objShell.Run("run.bat"), 0, True
```

Instead of running the batch file run the vb file.

Write it in notepad and save it as *.vbs

Comment: %batchfile% should be file.bat or %file.bat% or how does that work?

Comment: I just put that in as a placeholder for your batch file, where I have put "%batchfile%" just put your batch file path between the quotes

Comment: Example - objShell.Run("C:\batchfile.bat"), 0, True

Comment: very well, that code was good, can we run a .vbs file from autorun.inf?

Comment: Do you want to run the autorun.inf from removeable media?

Comment: @BaliC let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2128/discussion-between-green-code-and-bali-c)

Comment: I first though it actually solved the problem as described by the OP (no console window when clicking on the batch file itself), and it appears it doesn't. But then, it's still a nice and easy way of running a batch in a hidden window. So +1 anyway!

Answer (score 1):

If your Windows system supports powershell you can place this infront of "@echo off":

```
cmd /c powershell -Nop -NonI -Nologo -WindowStyle Hidden "Write-Host"
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, use VBS.

```
Set WinScriptHost = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WinScriptHost.Run Chr(34) & "C:\FilePath" & Chr(34), 0
Set WinScriptHost = Nothing
```

This is what I use.