# Hide cmd screen after running JAR

Tags: windows, jar, batch-file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hiding a simple batch window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941167/hiding-a-simple-batch-window)

I tried to run my JAR file with the following batch script:

```
@java -jar NelderMead.jar
```

And when the window of my application is shown I want to hide cmd screen behind it. How can I do it?

TIA!

Comment: Do you mean hide the cmd window that the batch file creates or the java program? If its the batch window then my answer to this question might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941167/hiding-a-simple-batch-window/6941198#6941198

Comment: thx! it works great! the last question is - how to make starting of application more common for users (like *.exe files). maybe I should write some code in cpp for example which will run batch file...

Comment: Great, yeah you could call it from a cpp exe or convert the batch file to .exe with a converter, like this - http://www.f2ko.de/programs.php?lang=en&pid=b2e

Answer (score 2):

Windows version of Java includes javaw.exe, which is exactly same as java but compiled as Win32 application and thus does not create console window. So use something like this:

```
@javaw -jar foo.jar
```

Comment: still see cmd window behind my app's window