# How to hide a console window that opens up with my application?

Tags: windows, matlab, windows-7, console-application, matlab-compiler

I have a console window which opens up together with my application. Can I somehow find its handle and hide it or at least minimize it? Suppose I can use any language (C++,C#,Visual Basic, Batch file, etc..)

I cannot remove the console, because every Matlab compiled application has one.

Comment: If you are using VS then you can use it as a Winform and it won't show the window.

Comment: Or see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941167/hiding-a-simple-batch-window/6941198#6941198 use a vbscript to open the file hidden.

Comment: Why open/create a Console window in the first place if you don't need one?

Comment: @CodyGray, It is opened up by Matlab compiled program :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're talking about an application that you compiled with inside MATLAB using `mcc`. If that's the case there is a flag that you can use.

Here's the blurb from the MATLAB documentation.

**-e Suppress MS-DOS Command Window**

Suppress appearance of the MS-DOS command window when generating a standalone application. Use -e in place of the -m option. This option is available for Windows only. Use with -R option to generate error logging as such:

**mcc -e -R -logfile -R 'filename' -v function_name**

When I deploy applications I usually leave the window open so when others see some kind of error they can report it to me. If you want to hide it definitely use the -R as suggested above to generate an error log.

Comment: Can I use this logfile in DLL compilations as well?

Answer (score 1):

To find the handle see: [How can I get a process handle by its name in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865152/how-can-i-get-a-process-handle-by-its-name-in-c)

Or if you are using cmd.exe to launch your program consider creating your own EXE from Visual Studio or using something like Python and www.py2exe.org to convert a Python script to an EXE.