# Batch-file to run executable on time interval

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to create a .bat file to execute a flash video on a 10 s time interval in an infinite loop.  So far I have...

```
ECHO OFF
:TOP
START /d "path" program.exe
SLEEP 10
TASKKILL /F /IM program.exe
GOTO TOP
```

It needs to restart the video after 10 seconds, but it just turns it on and that's it.  Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
@echo off
:TOP
PathDir\program.exe
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 11
taskkill /im program.exe /f
goto :TOP
```

Haven't changed much but I haven't used `SLEEP` so not sure if that's causing the issue.

Comment: Perfect!  Is there a way to run the command prompt in the background so it doesn't go over the video everytime?

Comment: Great :) See my answer here to hide the command prompt window - http://stackoverflow.com/a/6941198/799586

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
@color 0a
:top
echo sleeping... sleeping...
sleep 5
goto top
echo waking... yargh!!! how dare yee wake thy neighbroseph?!
```

Also be sure to have this .bat file residing in the same directory as Sleep.exe which can be found: http://www.computerhope.com/dutil.htm
Tested and working exactly how I'd hoped.